# Is there a positive integer base of numeration for which no equivalent of Benford's law holds?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Obviously a trivial equivalent of Benford's law holds in binary.

In trying to narrow it down, I thought about looking at just prime numbers, which maybe tells me nothing because some people say the primes don't satisfy Benford's law. I tried this query in Wolfram Alpha: `convert Prime[Range[100]] to ternary`

It also gave me a few other conversions, including quartal, octal and hexadecimal. Scanning those suggests that something like Benford's law also holds in those bases, though for octal to be more convincing I might have to go to $\pi(8^4)$ or something like that.

Comment: A quick Google search gives this [link](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath302/kmath302.htm) in support of Benford's law holding in arbitrary bases.

Comment: I would wager that it holds not only for positive integer bases but also for negative integer bases, fractional bases and imaginary bases.